# Is there any reliable open source that can proxy UDP traffic such as QUIC?

Tags: google-chrome, http, server, proxy, udp

Chrome/Chromium seem to support command line arguments for proxies, from the standard http, https proxies but also supports UDP proxy which is useful to proxy QUIC or HTTP/3 websites such as google own websites.

I could only find:

- https://github.com/liudanking/quic-proxy which had poor performance & has just chinese docs
- https://devsisters.github.io/goquic/ and a reverse proxy from also from korean group devsisters

If Chrome provides the ability to configure an UDP/QUIC/HTTP3 proxy, is there also a squid-like forward proxy that supports UDP and not just TCP as underlying protocol?

Comment: I don't see any such options in Chrome or Chromium. I see only HTTP and SOCKS proxy. Could you please explain which setting you think is for UDP/QUIC/HTTP3? Apart from that the question is likely off-topic, since not about programming. It might be more on-topic on [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: might also be on topic for serverfault.com or superuser.com if the question could be worded in an appropriate manner

Answer (score 4):

- Apache Traffic Server is a Proxy with experimental [Quick/http3](https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/en/9.0.x/admin-guide/files/records.config.en.html#http-3-configuration) Support, [starting with Version 9](https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/en/9.0.x/release-notes/whats-new.en.html).
- There is also some [recent work](https://github.com/caddyserver/forwardproxy/issues/72#issuecomment-616863553) on the forward-proxy Plugin for Caddyserver2, which also has [experimental http/3 support](https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/options#protocol).